# Solution on resource (css, images) sharing between IIS sub web applications

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a large website hosted in IIS, within it there are numbers of sub web applications. Each web application is developed with either an ASP.NET WebForm application or ASP.NET MVC application. All the web applications work together to enable the web site.

So, question: is there a best solution to share common resources (css, images, js) among the applications? Currently, all the resources are duplicated in each web application and it is quite a pain to maintain them.

Comment: Question here is what you're trying to achieve ? Fast page-load or good maintainability ?

Comment: good maintainability: solutions to remove code duplication.Since all the sub web applications should have the same look and feel, they should use the same ASP.NET master page, but I don't find a way to share master page among different web applications, the workaround is duplicate the master page code (aspx, css, js, images) in all web applications.